# register_globals still working, why?

Tags: php, debugging, register-globals

In my `php.ini` I have `register_globals=Off`

But still if I visit

```
`/testing/testing.php?abc=19`
```

then value of `abc=19` is shown by using `echo $_REQUEST['abc']`.
Question is why still I can access value of `abc` variable?

`Note: I am using XAMPP.`

Comment: Have you tried to restart the server?

Comment: yes did it,still works the same way @mbanzon

Comment: Wut? `echo $_REQUEST['abc']` displays the value? There's nothing wrong with that and it has nothing to do with register_globals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking why you can give `register_globals=Off` and `$_REQUEST['abc']` will be set. That's not relevant to how `register_globals` works.

[`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) sets a global variable with the name of the URL key. So in this case you could do `echo $abc;` and the code would work fine if `register_globals` was enabled and would cause an error if it was disabled.

`$_REQUEST` (like `$_GET` and `$_POST`) is a [*super*-global](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), and will be available whatever setting you give.

Answer (score 2):

even if off/on `register_gloabls` $_GET and $_POST will have parameters which are coming from request

when you set `register_globals=On`

request like http://www.example.com/?abc=1&temp=3

then php will create variable with name `abc` and `temp` and assigns value 1,3 respectively.